# find all positive solutions of $\frac{\ln^2(x^2)}{x^2} = \pi^2$

Tags: calculus, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

This is a riddle I have to solve.
What is surprising is the "all positive solutions" .
Obviously this equation involves the Lambert function, but "positive' is meaningless for complex numbers...
I have currently 4 solutions, 0.4745409994, -0.4745409994, i and -i, but one single positive (real) solution.
However, the riddle solution must contain more that one value.

The problem is stated exactly like in the title of my question, not $\frac{\ln(x^2)}{x^2}^2 = \pi^2$

Could this be the trick ? $\ln(\ln(x)) = \ln^2(x)$ ?

Comment: Finding all positive solutions does not mean there must be more than one.

Comment: If you interpret $\ln^2(x^2)$ as $\ln(\ln(x^2))$, then there are [no real solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28pi+x%29%5E2-ln+ln+%28x%5E2%29).

Comment: Taking it as $\left(2\frac{\ln x}x\right)^2=\pi^2$, you get some solutions from $2\ln x=\pi x$, and the line vs. the logarithm says there are at most two positive real solutions.

Comment: @abiessu: $2\ln x=\pi x$ has no real solutions (but $2\ln x=-\pi x$ has one real solution).

Comment: @TonyK: true I meant to say "there might be solutions from..."

Answer (score 2):

*Without Lambert function.*

Consider that you look for the zero's of  function
$$f(x)=\log ^2\left(x^2\right)-\pi ^2 x^2$$ Let $x^2=t$ to make it
$$g(t)=\log ^2\left(t\right)-\pi ^2 t\implies g'(t)=\frac{2 \log (t)}{t}-\pi ^2$$ Since $\forall t \,\,\, \log(t)<t$, then $ g'(t)< 0  \,\,\,\forall t$. If the is a root, it is unique and since $g(t)$ veries from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$, the root does exist.

Answer (score 1):

The positive real solution you got seems to be unique.

We can evaluate:
$$\ln^2(x^2)=(x\pi)^2\to \ln(x^2)=x\pi\to x^2=e^{\pi x}\to e^{x\pi}-x^2=0$$

Yes, I ignored negative roots here, but it doesn't matter here because the real roots will have the same absolute value.

What matters here is that $f(x)=e^{x\pi}-x^2\implies f'(x)=\pi e^{\pi x}-2x>0\forall x\in\Bbb R^+$ (and you can check the same for $e^{-\pi x}-x^2$ and $e^{\pi x}-x^{-2}$)  so the function is monotone and will only have one solution.

Comment: What about $\ln(x^2)=-x\pi$ with solution $x=\exp(-W(\pi/2))$ ?

Comment: Well this evaluates to $e^{-\pi x}-x^2=0$, setting $y=-x$ yields $$e^{\pi y}-y^2=0$$ so the solution will just be the negative of the solution to $f(x)$. OP found both $0.475...$ and $-0.475...$.

Comment: @RhysHughes: no, $2\ln x=\pi x$ and $2\ln x=-\pi x$ may both have positive solutions in $x$ which clearly cannot be negatives of each other.

Comment: @abiessu:  I think that 2ln(x)=πx has no solution in Reals. The only solution is x = i

Comment: Is $ln^2(x)$ a standard writing for $ln(ln(x))$ ? This could be the trick of the riddle ...

Comment: This is correct @user863967. The derivatives demonstrate as much. And, if you evaluate $\ln(x^2)$ as $2\ln(|x|)$, the solutions are the negatives of each other.

Comment: I've never seen $\ln^2(x)$ mean anything other than $(\ln(x))^2$, much like $f^2(x)=(f(x))^2$

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Lambert W function to solve for $x$.
$$\begin{align*} \left(\dfrac{\ln (x)}{x}\right)^2=\pi^2\end{align*}$$
\begin{array}{lll}%
&\ln(x) = x\pi  \quad &  \ln(x) = -x\pi  \\
\implies& x=\exp(-W(-\pi)) \qquad  \implies &= \exp(-W(\pi))
\end{array}

Hence the two solutions are $\exp(-W(-\pi))\approx-0.159-0.585i$ and $\exp(-W(\pi))\approx 0.342$

Comment: Note that it should be $x^2$ inside the logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

Assuming that there is a typo, 
this  is a minimal correction,
with which the phrase  "all positive solutions"
is justified:

\begin{align}
\tfrac1{x^2}\,\ln(x^2)^2 &= \tfrac1{\pi^2}
,\\
\tfrac1x\,\ln(x^2) &= \pm\tfrac1{\pi}
,\\ 
\tfrac1x\,\ln(x) &=\pm\tfrac1{2\,\pi}
,\\
-\tfrac1x\,\ln(x) &= \pm\tfrac1{2\,\pi}
,\\
\tfrac1x\,\ln(\tfrac1x) &= \pm\tfrac1{2\,\pi}
,\\
\ln(\tfrac1x)&=\W(\pm\tfrac1{2\,\pi})
,\\
\tfrac1x&=\exp( \W(\pm\tfrac1{2\,\pi}))
,\\
x&=\exp(-\W(\pm\tfrac1{2\,\pi}))
.
\end{align}

And there are three distinct real solutions:

\begin{align} 
x&=\exp(-\W(\tfrac1{2\,\pi})) \approx 0.8706
,\\
x&=\exp(-\Wp(-\tfrac1{2\,\pi})) \approx 1.2129
,\\
x&=\exp(-\Wm(-\tfrac1{2\,\pi})) \approx 18.2460
.
\end{align}

$\endgroup$

Comment: unfortunately, there is no typo, here is how the problem is stated: https://enigmes-a-thematiques.fr/web/enigmes/images/ep2401.png